# Make the mouse cursor on text areas narrower in Gnome and KDE

Tags: gnome, kde, cursor

E.g. the select text cursors in all distributions and desktop environments I have tried are unusable. I need 1 pixel width and not 3 or more pixel width like it's currently on all DE including Cinnamon, Gnome, KDE, etc.

Selecting text in Linux is so much more difficult than in Windows where the select text cursor is only 1 px wide and very easy to use.

I don't mind the arrows, i.e. the arrow pointer in Unity is nice and practical, but the select text cursors are so hard to use when you have strings like "lll" and you need to select only one of them using a select cursorthat is probably 3 times wider than the character you want to select.

I am sure that I am not the only one who has noticed this difference while switching between Linux and Windows machines on a daily basis. It's especially annoying when the text you want to select is very small and the "sharp" select text cursor comes very handy.

Is there any legal reason why the DE for Linux do not provide the 1 px wide select text cursor.

**UPDATE:** This is what you can experience on Windows 7, but not on Linux ;(:

**Dark text and light background**

[image: Dark text and light background]

**Light text on dark background**

[image]

**Unusual mixed situation**

[image]

**Some areas of the cursor will change the color based on the background**
[image]

Comment: I can't speak for the others, but KDE lets you pick whatever theme you want. I'm using Breeze's text cursor. It's three pixels wide (I think). The middle pixel is black, and the outer two are white. This is necessary, otherwise it'd be invisible on a black background. And no, AFAIK there is no patent on a one-pixel wide I-beam.

Comment: I just went to the CNN website and to their footer which is black and my select text  cursor was white. So, this is probably something with unability of Linux DE to change the cursor color based on the background? I am currently on Windows 7 with no theme enhancements. I have never had any problem selecting a text on a Windows machine, but I struggle with text selection on every Linux distribution with the default cursor set. It's one thing that I don't understand, because I am sure that i am not the only one who noticed this difference while switching between Linux and Windows machines.

Comment: Huh… interesting. What happens if the top half of the beam is over a white background and the bottom half is over a black background?

Comment: @Sparhawk it's hard to do, because the cursor is changing to an arrow as soon as I leave the text, but I will try to custom-style it via the developer debug tool and make a screenshot

Comment: @Sparhawk Here is the screenshot of this unusual mixed situation in Windows where part of the cursor is on dark and part on light background: http://imgur.com/v2KVHRt

Comment: Any idea why this I-beam cursor color inverting feature is not supported by Xorg or Wayland etc.?

Comment: Thanks for the pictures. I have no idea. I guess it's probably just one of those things that hasn't been written (yet).

Comment: Cursors are chosen by applications, not by the desktop environment, but applications using Gnome libraries should use the Gnome theme and so on. Without doing anything, in most applications, my mouse cursor on a text area is either a black vertical line one pixel wide with white vertical lines one pixel wide on each side (plus some horizontal lines at the top and at the bottom), or the same with black and white inverted. Is that what you mean by three pixels wide, or do you get a cursor that's three pixels wide with the same color? Have you tried changing the graphical theme?

Comment: @Gilles Yes, 3px consisting of 1px white left, 1px black middle and 1px white right. Some DEs use only 2px wide vertical "line" where 1px on the left is black and 1px on the right is white. That's pretty much everything what you can get. Check [this gif](http://imgur.com/a/IxG7w) where you can see how it works in Windows 7. Notice that it's only 1px wide and parts of the cursor changes color based on the background.